# Global value or cache for ng-repeat / ngRepeat in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to keep a global value or some sort of cache out of `ngRepeat`. It is a bit complicated to explain so here is what I'd like to do.

I used the example code from [docs:ngRepeat](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat).

```
<body>
  <div ng-init="friends = [
    {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
  ]">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends>
      {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to sum up the `age` value on every repetition. The result should look like this:

- John who is 25 years old. **25** - *explanation: 25+0*
- Jessie who is 30 years old. **55** - *explanation: 25+30*
- Johanna who is 28 years old. **83** - *explanation: 55+28*
- Joy who is 15 years old. **98** - *explanation: 83+15*
- ...

A Plunkr for experiments can be found here [http://plnkr.co/edit/VFiTOnmQ4cyqgNMDa9L4](http://plnkr.co/edit/VFiTOnmQ4cyqgNMDa9L4?p=preview).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```html
<ul ng-init="ages = []">
  <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old. 
    {{ ages[$index] = (friend.age + ages[$index-1]) }} 
    - explanation {{friend.age }} + {{ 0 + ages[$index-1]}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8XCt3j?p=preview